# request.getAttribute("user") returning null object

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-mvc

I am trying to send object of User class to success.jsp. But getting null when trying to retrieve the object in success.jsp.

Code for UserController:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/user")
public class UserController {


@PostMapping("/login")
public String Register(@Valid @ModelAttribute("user") User user,Errors errors,Model model) {
    System.out.println("....done....");
    
    if(errors.hasErrors()) {
        return "user";
    }
    else {
         RegisterService.show(user);
        
         model.addAttribute("user",user);
        
         
        return "redirect:/success";
    }
        
}
```

}

Code for success.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
   
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>

<%@ page import="com.company.models.User" %>
    
<body>

    Registration Successful
    
    <%
        User user=(User)request.getAttribute("user");
    
        System.out.println("user="+user);
    %>
    
    
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use RedirectAttributes to send data to the page even if you are redirecting.

example:

```
@PostMapping("/login")
    public String Register(@Valid @ModelAttribute("user") User user,Errors errors, RedirectAttributes attributes) {
     System.out.println("....done....");
     if(errors.hasErrors()) {
         return "user";
     }
     else {
         RegisterService.show(user);
         attributes.addFlashAttribute("user", user);
         return "redirect:/success";
     }
 }
```

read the documentation at: https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/support/RedirectAttributes.html

Answer (score 0):

It was because I was sending a redirect to success.jsp. So cannot pass data

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).